# Rails application taking more than 30 seconds to respond

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I'm making a small rails application that fetch data from some different languages at github-api.
The problem is, when i click the button that will fetch the informations, it takes a long time to redirect to the correct page. What i got from network is, the TTFB is actually 30s (!) and is getting a response with the status 302.

The controller function that is doing the logic:

```
  Language.delete_all
  search_urls = Introduction.all.map { |introduction| "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=#{introduction.name}&per_page=1" }
  search_urls.each do |search_url|
    json_file = JSON.parse(open(search_url).read)
    pl = Language.new
    pl.hash_response = json_file['items'].first
    pl.name = pl.hash_response['language']
    pl.save
  end

  main_languages = %w[ruby javascript python elixir java]
  deletable_languages = Introduction.all.reject do |introduction|
    main_languages.include?(introduction.name)
  end
  deletable_languages.each do |language|
    language.delete
  end

  redirect_to languages_path
end
```

Comment: That's because you are doing a lot of stuff in your controller. First you have queries without any filters (where(...)), filtering with ruby in most of the scenarios is slower than the db. Second, you "open" all those urls and so on.. Honestly 30 sec is fast for what's in that controller. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bottleneck is the http request in which you are doing it one by one. You could have filtered the languages that you want before generating the url and fetch them.

However, if the count of the urls after filtered is still large, say 20-50, assuming each request take 200ms, this would take at least 4s to 10s just for http request. Thats already too long for the user to wait for. In that case you should make it a background job.

If you insist to do this synchronously, you may consider fire those http requess by spawning multiple threads and join all the results after all threads are completed. You will achieve some concurrency here as the GIL will not block thread for IO wait. But this is very prone to error as you need to manage the threads on your own.